# Extracting information from 2 documents using mongodb driver

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I have three different collections.
The first collection is User, (userId, name, address.. etc)
the second collection is service, (serviceId, name, title)
the third collection is service2User(serviceId, and recipientUserId)

(I know i could use some array inside the service instead of the service2User
this is done because the serviceRegister2User contain much more then 2 fields, and can be very big.)

I need to find a collection of users which don't have current service (i.e service=10)
(the solution can be done by: linq or directly through the c# mongo driver)

to my best understand this is a two process action

First: I need to search the serviceRegister2User collection and find all recipientUserId which have  already serviceId=10.

Second: I need to find all users which are different from the users found in my first query.
those users are users which did not register to serviceId=10

The collection found after the second process is the wanted result.

Can someone tell me how to do it in both way?
- linq or directly through the c# mongo driver

if it is done by Linq driver, then it need to return MongoCollection.
Thank you.